# xbee & xbee pro series 1 interoperability

Tags: xbee

Is it possible for XBee Series 1 (802.15.4) and XBee Pro Series 1 units to communicate? I have two units but I cannot get them communicate. Standard XBee to Standard XBee works just fine but I cannot communicate (either send or receive) when the Pro unit is involved. Are they interoperable?

TIA

Comment: They should work, as long as the non-Pro unit is close enough for its signal to reach the Pro unit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if both have implemented the zigbee protocol (I understand in xBee series 1, the main difference between Pro and "normal" is that Pro xbees have zigBee protocol to communicate, but "normal" haven't, so the communication must be imposible.

You should read this website in order to clear and order your mind:

https://www.sparkfun.com/pages/xbee_guide

EDIT: Now I have seen the question date, I hope you have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this once with Xbee S2 and Xbee S2B. They both have same kind of structure when i opened it in XCTU. They both communicated in both AP and API mode.
When i tried this with Xbee S2 and Xbee S2C, the communication could not take place in AP and API mode. This because when i opened them in XCTU, they both had different kind of structure.
I think, i same logic will work in Xbee S1 also.